# Zapier is binding data response from GET request?

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I am trying to manipulate a response from GET request, but Zapier is binding all the response data. Please see the image. Is this true, or there are ways around this?

This is the response from Zapier's GET.
[image]

Please point me a correct direction. 
[image]
[image]

Here is the raw version:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 19235266,
      "text": "Start of chat (WhatsApp)",
      "photo": null,
      "coordinates": null,
      "transport": "whatsapp",
      "type": "from_client",
      "read": true,
      "created": "2018-03-22T08:52:31 UTC",
      "audio": null,
      "pdf": null,
      "remote_id": null,
      "recipient_status": null,
      "operator_id": 8645,
      "channel_id": 1524,
      "dialog_id": 903974,
      "client_id": 1704911
    },
    {
      "id": 19235267,
      "text": "Chat agent – Administrator",
      "photo": null,
      "coordinates": null,
      "transport": "whatsapp",
      "type": "system",
      "read": true,
      "created": "2018-03-22T08:52:31 UTC",
      "audio": null,
      "pdf": null,
      "remote_id": null,
      "recipient_status": null,
      "operator_id": null,
      "channel_id": 1524,
      "dialog_id": 903974,
      "client_id": 1704911
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question do include the raw `GET` request? or at least a short version so we can see the structure? Do you control the structure of the request?

Comment: Nope, I am requesting the block of information as it is.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Luckily, the fix here is very simple. If you want access to the raw hook (instead of the way we process it) you should use the `Catch Raw Hook` trigger:

[image]

Then you'll get your full body as a **string**:

[image]

and you can do whatever you'd like with it. For example, I wrote a small code step to pull the id of the first item:

```js
let j = JSON.parse(inputData.data)

return {emails: j.data}
```

Which worked as expected. Note that if you return an array from a code step, subsequent steps will happen for **each item**. Proceed with caution when processing a bunch of items.

Comment: Okay let me give it a try, thank you so much for the feedback.

Comment: Okay so I am getting the raw body, but the way I have setup zap is that, first step is the raw catch hook, second is the GET action to request raw body and this is where the issue is. I cannot access the GET response, since it is binding it as I mentioned earlier. 

I want to access the GET response like you have mentioned in the code above. My apologies, I am learning this platform.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow - what is your second step? what request do you need to do once your hook has arrived?

Comment: Once I receive my hook, there are two ids I receive with the hooks, I will need to make a GET request using those two Ids.

So hook response is: {"dialog_id":"941951","channel_id":"1524"}

My next step is to make a GET request using the dialog_id and channel_id. 

api.sdsad.com/v1/messages?

qstring using channel & dialog ids from first step.

Comment: So the issue I am facing is not with the hook, but the rather GET response data.

Comment: what do you need to do with the data after that? are you doing actions once per data item or on them all in one go?

Comment: I want to formulate an email, I want to run through each data block 

data[0].type data[0].text data[0].pdf
data[1].type data[1].text data[1].pdf... 
data[n-1].type data[n-1].text data[n-1].pdf

Comment: Ah, got it. do you want one email or an email for each item in the GET request?

Comment: One email for each GET request.

Comment: Oh perfect! so in that case, return the array of emails (i've updated my code). when testing it'll look like it's only returning one email, but when it runs for real it'll work as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170719/discussion-between-jignesh-and-xavdid).